# How to serialize/deserialize a FlexiProvider KeyPair using Gson?

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization

I'm try to serialize and deserialize a key pair (obtained from the FlexiProvider key pair generator) using Gson, but I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for
>   interface java.security.PrivateKey. Register an InstanceCreator with
>   Gson for this type may fix this problem.

This is the code that I use to generate the `KeyPair` and save it as Gson to a file:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
CurveParams ecParams = new CurveRegistry.BrainpoolP160r1();
kpg.initialize(ecParams, new SecureRandom());
key = kpg.generateKeyPair();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String serializedKeyPair = gson.toJson(key)
```

And this is the code to deserialize:

```
KeyPair key = new Gson().fromJson(serializedKeyPair, KeyPair.class);
```

Any help please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of why you're getting this error is that GSON does not know how to instantiate `java.security.KeyPair` that should accept both *abstract and not concrete* `java.security.PrivateKey` and `java.security.PublicKey`. GSON supports a special mechanism that allows to write custom type adapters for any non-built-in type (see [`JsonSerializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) and [`JsonDeserializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)). Even if you register a custom type adapter, you won't be able to deserialize them due to lack of information about the *concrete* type the FlexiProvider needs to work.

More over, the FlexiProvider types are complex and extremely hard to be deeply-serialized manually (when you deal with specific every type face to face; and not even not sure if it's possible to instantiate those types due to theirs protection level), so, as a workaround, you can rely on GSON ability to serialize and deserialize *any class by its non-transient fields*. Note that no accessors are required (neither getter, nor setter), and no constructors are required. Simply speaking, GSON allows you to create an exact snapshot of an object internal state except of its transient fields.

If you're fine with holding an additional synthetic field in JSONs, then welcome.

## ClassAwareSerializer.java

The only responsibility of this class is "remember" the exact class of the source object in order to restore it later.

- The `CLASS_FIELD_NAME` is a name of a special JSON object synthentic field that keeps the original class name. Its value may look weird, but I'm almost sure it's enough to avoid any fields clashing by specifying a very "rare" combination of the characters with a special prefix `\u0001`.
- The `expectedClass` field holds the original class, and the serializer/deserializer makes necessary checks to guarantee that the exact classes are restored ("exact" means a class and its subclasses).
- The `gsonSupplier` fields holds a GSON instance supplier in order to avoid cyclic references that would prevent from the classes to be properly initialized (laziness is cool and may help when you want to avoid eagerly evaluated values).

```java
final class ClassAwareSerializer<T>
        implements JsonSerializer<T>, JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private static final String CLASS_FIELD_NAME = "\u0001$class";

    private final Class<T> expectedClass;
    private final Supplier<Gson> gsonSupplier;

    private ClassAwareSerializer(final Class<T> expectedClass, final Supplier<Gson> gsonSupplier)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.expectedClass = expectedClass;
        this.gsonSupplier = gsonSupplier;
    }

    static <T> ClassAwareSerializer<T> getClassAwareSerializer(final Class<T> expectedClass, final Supplier<Gson> gsonSupplier) {
        return new ClassAwareSerializer<>(expectedClass, gsonSupplier);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final T o, final Type type, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if ( o == null ) {
            return JsonNull.INSTANCE;
        }
        final Class<?> actualClass = o.getClass();
        requireExpectedClass(expectedClass, actualClass);
        final Gson gson = gsonSupplier.get();
        final JsonObject jsonObject = gson.toJsonTree(o).getAsJsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty(CLASS_FIELD_NAME, actualClass.getName());
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            final String className = jsonObject.get(CLASS_FIELD_NAME).getAsString();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Class<T> actualClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className);
            requireExpectedClass(expectedClass, actualClass);
            final Gson gson = gsonSupplier.get();
            return gson.fromJson(json, actualClass);
        } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
            throw new JsonParseException(ex);
        } catch ( final Exception ex ) {
            final String name = getClass().getName();
            throw new JsonParseException(name + " cannot handle " + type, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void requireExpectedClass(final Class<?> expectedClass, final Class<?> actualClass) {
        if ( !expectedClass.isAssignableFrom(actualClass) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(actualClass + " is not assignable from " + expectedClass);
        }
    }

}
```

## FlexiTypeAdapterFactory.java

This class is a sort of a registry where you encapsulate the classes you need in order to restore the object state. All of the registered classes are either `abstract` or `interface`s so it's necessary to keep the original class name for them during serialization and deserialization: `CurveParams`, `EllipticCurve`, `GFElement`, `Point` from the FlexiProvider packages, and `java.security.PrivateKey` and `java.security.PublicKey` that are effectively `ECPrivateKey` and `ECPublicKey` respectively.

```java
final class FlexiTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory flexiTypeAdapterFactory = new FlexiTypeAdapterFactory();

    private static final Gson internalGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(CurveParams.class, getClassAwareSerializer(CurveParams.class, FlexiTypeAdapterFactory::getInternalGson))
            .registerTypeAdapter(EllipticCurve.class, getClassAwareSerializer(EllipticCurve.class, FlexiTypeAdapterFactory::getInternalGson))
            .registerTypeAdapter(GFElement.class, getClassAwareSerializer(GFElement.class, FlexiTypeAdapterFactory::getInternalGson))
            .registerTypeAdapter(Point.class, getClassAwareSerializer(Point.class, FlexiTypeAdapterFactory::getInternalGson))
            .registerTypeAdapter(PrivateKey.class, getClassAwareSerializer(PrivateKey.class, FlexiTypeAdapterFactory::getInternalGson))
            .registerTypeAdapter(PublicKey.class, getClassAwareSerializer(PublicKey.class, FlexiTypeAdapterFactory::getInternalGson))
            .create();

    private FlexiTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getFlexiTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return flexiTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {
        return internalGson.getAdapter(type);
    }

    private static Gson getInternalGson() {
        return internalGson;
    }

}
```

## FlexiDemo.java

And here is the demo:

```java
public final class FlexiDemo {

    private FlexiDemo() {
    }

    static {
        // register the FlexiECProvider
        addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());
    }

    // similarly to the "registry" above, make an "uber" registry
    private static final Gson flexiGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getFlexiTypeAdapterFactory())
            .create();

    public static void main(final String... args)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        // create a state
        final State state = initiate();
        // dump the payload to stdout
        out.println(state.keyPairJson);
        // ensure that the key pair has been restored correctly
        validate(state);
    }

    private static State initiate()
            throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException {
        final KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
        final AlgorithmParameterSpec algorithmParameterSpec = new BrainpoolP160r1();
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(algorithmParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
        final KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        // create a signature to sign with
        final Signature toSignWith = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA", "FlexiEC");
        toSignWith.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        final byte[] message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes();
        toSignWith.update(message);
        // create a state to be passed to the consumer method
        return new State(message, toSignWith.sign(), flexiGson.toJson(keyPair));
    }

    private static void validate(final State state)
            throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        // deserialize the key pair from the state
        final KeyPair keyPair = flexiGson.fromJson(state.keyPairJson, KeyPair.class);
        // create a signature to verify with
        final Signature toVerifyWith = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA", "FlexiEC");
        toVerifyWith.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
        toVerifyWith.update(state.message);
        // verify it's fine
        if ( !toVerifyWith.verify(state.signature) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Signature is not valid");
        }
    }

    private static final class State {

        private final byte[] message;
        private final byte[] signature;
        private final String keyPairJson;

        private State(final byte[] message, final byte[] signature, final String keyPairJson) {
            this.message = message;
            this.signature = signature;
            this.keyPairJson = keyPairJson;
        }

    }

}
```

If the key pair was not deserialized correctly, then it should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. So this is what I'm getting for the example above:

> {"privateKey":{"mS":{"bigInt":822041982056381306903337881735786906176674585536},"mParams":{"oid":{"value_":[1,3,36,3,3,2,8,1,1,1],"optional_":false,"explicit_":true},"q":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"E":{"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"g":{"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mX":{"mValue":{"bigInt":1089473557631435284577962539738532515920566082499},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mY":{"mValue":{"bigInt":127912481829969033206777085249718746721365418785},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mZ":{"mValue":{"bigInt":1},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mE":{"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.PointGFP"},"r":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085038830181364212942568457},"k":1,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry$BrainpoolP160r1"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECPrivateKey"},"publicKey":{"mW":{"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mX":{"mValue":{"bigInt":898050308678420953722928302444207549290702194327},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mY":{"mValue":{"bigInt":1055211912601204440980166844947376095404031588451},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mZ":{"mValue":{"bigInt":1},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mE":{"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.PointGFP"},"mParams":{"oid":{"value_":[1,3,36,3,3,2,8,1,1,1],"optional_":false,"explicit_":true},"q":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"E":{"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"g":{"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mX":{"mValue":{"bigInt":1089473557631435284577962539738532515920566082499},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mY":{"mValue":{"bigInt":127912481829969033206777085249718746721365418785},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mZ":{"mValue":{"bigInt":1},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mE":{"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mA":{"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.PointGFP"},"r":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085038830181364212942568457},"k":1,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry$BrainpoolP160r1"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECPublicKey"}}

And the JSON above is deserialized and, at least, signature verification is performed without issues.

## Edit 1

These FlexiProvider classes use `de.flexiprovider.common.math.FlexiBigInt` heavily and it's internal structure is quite simple: it's just a wrapper around `java.math.BigInteger`. Since the latter can be saved as a single literal, you can implement a `FlexiBigInt` serializer/deserializer and register it in `FlexiTypeAdapterFactory`.

### FlexiBigIntSerializer.java

```java
final class FlexiBigIntSerializer
        implements JsonSerializer<FlexiBigInt>, JsonDeserializer<FlexiBigInt> {

    private static final FlexiBigIntSerializer flexiBigIntSerializer = new FlexiBigIntSerializer();

    private FlexiBigIntSerializer() {
    }

    static FlexiBigIntSerializer getFlexiBigIntSerializer() {
        return flexiBigIntSerializer;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final FlexiBigInt flexiBigInt, final Type type, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(flexiBigInt.bigInt);
    }

    @Override
    public FlexiBigInt deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        return new FlexiBigInt(json.getAsString());
    }

}
```

A sample output would be as follows:

> {"privateKey":{"mS":157082674866934426557053639991687482446678589470,"mParams":{"oid":{"value_":[1,3,36,3,3,2,8,1,1,1],"optional_":false,"explicit_":true},"q":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"E":{"mQ":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"g":{"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mX":{"mValue":1089473557631435284577962539738532515920566082499,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mY":{"mValue":127912481829969033206777085249718746721365418785,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mZ":{"mValue":1,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mE":{"mQ":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.PointGFP"},"r":1332297598440044874827085038830181364212942568457,"k":1,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry$BrainpoolP160r1"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECPrivateKey"},"publicKey":{"mW":{"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mX":{"mValue":617372660513155950230702702463764172736812817527,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mY":{"mValue":181720905517452391311740613249776603549059113329,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mZ":{"mValue":1,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mE":{"mQ":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.PointGFP"},"mParams":{"oid":{"value_":[1,3,36,3,3,2,8,1,1,1],"optional_":false,"explicit_":true},"q":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"E":{"mQ":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"g":{"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mX":{"mValue":1089473557631435284577962539738532515920566082499,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mY":{"mValue":127912481829969033206777085249718746721365418785,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mZ":{"mValue":1,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mE":{"mQ":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"mA":{"mValue":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"mB":{"mValue":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088,"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.finitefields.GFPElement"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.EllipticCurveGFP"},"mP":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.common.math.ellipticcurves.PointGFP"},"r":1332297598440044874827085038830181364212942568457,"k":1,"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry$BrainpoolP160r1"},"\u0001$class":"de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECPublicKey"}}

You can save 12% of space taken if non-pretty output or 195/321 lines for pretty output.

Comment: You are an hero, because not only you helped me with the code, but also because you explained it in details! I'd like to add just a thing: make sure to use the right imports in FlexiTypeAdapterFactory: java.security.PrivateKey and java.security.PublicKey (instead of de.flexiprovider.api.keys.PublicKey etc).  Thank you very much mate!